# Not able show Top & bottom items in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview in my project but bottom items are not displayed in recyclerview.
I tried ScrollView but my app is crashing it shows `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child` this error.
Here is my code

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyler_transaction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add your RecyclerView code and screenshots so it will be easy to understand what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: add some code about what you have done then someone can help you in your problem

Comment: Also be clear about what technology you are talking about.  I can infer that you are using Java (probably) but it would help if you clarified that and, as mentioned above, include some code samples that illustrate the issue you are running into.

Comment: @gulabpatel 
 plz check i have added the code

Comment: @Dashesh plz check my code

Comment: You dont need Scrollview if you are using RecylerView. Please go through Recycleview tutorials on blogs or youtube to implement it correctly.

Comment: Scrollview can contain only one child layout. Means in scrollview scope add one linear layout and then add all views inside that linear layout. Recyclerview and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rcview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
```

Implement your RecyclerView in this manner. You dont need ScrollView to add recyclerview. Recyclerview can scroll by itself.
It will be good of you can add your whole xml and Adapter code.

Comment: Still not able to see bottom items

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: If the solution worked can you accept the answer..

Comment: yeah it worked for constraint layout in activity,but now hv done some changes means i replaced activity with fragment and added bottom navigation ans toolbar so facing same problem..top and bottom items are not visible

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the **recyclerview** as parent layout that this work is wrong, because **recyclerview** in android just get a adapter that it, and you most use the container layout like **scrollbar**s for show another layout inside it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have added more than one `ViewGroup` as a child of your `ScrollView`. `ScrollView` must contain at most one child in order to properly calculate the height of the view.

Below sample code is wrong:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ....
        ....
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ....
        ....
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In order to solve the problem, you can use the below sample code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- here add your views -->
        ....
        ....
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried ur solution but still facing same problem..not able to see bottom items

Comment: Show us the full xml file and a screenshot of your UI.

Comment: I have added plz check